# Why do I get "caller uid xxxxx is different than the authenticator's uid" when accessing another app's account information?

Tags: android, accountmanager

I wrote an app, A, which uses AccountManager for login handling.  Then, I wrote another app, B, which use A's AccountManager account data.

But when I run B, I get "java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid xxxx is different than the authenticator's uid".

Signing B with A's keystore file solves this problem.

However, I still want to know why this happens and whether there's an alternate solution.

Answer (score 3):

This message is highly misleading. You can only access another accounts information if you have the same uid or same signature as the application that has the Account Authenticator. There is NO other solution.  They would do well to change the message.

This is an important security precaution. If it didn't have this any app could read anyone elses user data. This could contain sensetive information.

Source: Read the code

Comment: Well, it's not entirely correct that "there is NO other solution". As outlined in the [Account Manager: Using other accounts](http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-using-other-accounts) article, apps can use OAuth to use accounts whose authenticator was provided by a different app. However, that requires the user to re-enter the password once. Also see this related blog article about how to [Write your own Android Authenticator](http://udinic.wordpress.com/tag/accountauthenticator/).

Comment: Well depends on what he is talking about. I thought he was talking about getting user data which there is not other way than what I laid out above. However, to get tokens the user can approve it and other apps can get access to it.